# How to fetch the last 5 data's from JSON using PHP?

Tags: php

past 1 hour am struggling with this task, actually, I have to fetch the last 5 updated data from members.json.

Actually, I have one form if we submit that form values, that values are stored in a members.json page with JSON format.

Now how to fetch the postdate value in loop condition using PHP, I updated my JSON and index.php code below. Thanks advance

#### members.json

```json
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "urli": "test1",
            "title": "test1",
            "content": "Test1Test1Test1Test1",
            "postdate": "December 31, 2018",
            "hashtags": "#Christ #Love",
            "image": "test1"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "urli": "test2",
            "title": "test2",
            "content": "Test2Test2Test2Test2Test2",
            "postdate": "December 31, 2018",
            "hashtags": "#Faith Test2",
            "image": "test2"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "urli": "test3",
            "title": "Test3",
            "content": "Test3Test3Test3Test3",
            "postdate": "December 31, 2018",
            "hashtags": "#Faith #Christ",
            "image": "test3"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "urli": "test4",
            "title": "Test4",
            "content": "Test4Test4Test4Test4",
            "postdate": "December 31, 2018",
            "hashtags": "#Sermons Test4Test4",
            "image": "test4"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "urli": "test5",
            "title": "Test5",
            "content": "Test4Test4Test5Test5Test5",
            "postdate": "December 31, 2018",
            "hashtags": "#Christ #Love Test5",
            "image": "test5"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "urli": "test6",
            "title": "test6",
            "content": "Test6Test6Test6Test6Test6",
            "postdate": "December 31, 2018",
            "hashtags": "#Sermons #Faith #Christ #Love",
            "image": "test6"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "urli": "test7",
            "title": "Test7",
            "content": "Test7Test7Test7Test7",
            "postdate": "December 31, 2018",
            "hashtags": "#Sermons #Faith #Christ #Love",
            "image": "test7"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "urli": "test8",
            "title": "Test8",
            "content": "Test8Test8Test8Test8Test8",
            "postdate": "December 31, 2018",
            "hashtags": "#Sermons #Faith #Christ #Love",
            "image": "test8"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "urli": "test8",
            "title": "Test8",
            "content": "Test8Test8Test8Test8Test8",
            "postdate": "jan 01, 2019",
            "hashtags": "#Sermons #Faith #Christ #Love",
            "image": "test8"
        }
    ]
```

#### index.php

```html
<div class="padding">
    <h1>
        <a href="single.html"></a>
    </h1>
    <div class="detail">
        <div class="time">December 22, 2016</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Did you try something? In fact - you've to decode your json, then sort(probably by ID) and iterate over it.

Comment: All of your `postdate` fields are the same. You cannot determine any update order unless storing the micro time.

Comment: [`array_slice($array, -5, 5)`](http://php.net/array_slice) if they're stored in order already.

Comment: -mario @ thank you, will try and lets see. that members.json page json have to updated day by day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After decoding the json data into array using array_slice last 5 values can be obtained.

```
$data= json_decode($data , true);
$values = array_slice($data, -5);
```

for reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_slice.asp

Answer (score 3):

```html
$array = json_decode($data , true);

$items = array_slice($array, -5);
```

decode the json data to array then use array_slice.